How to access a variable inside an array in Vue JS
Javascript and Vue beginner here. Trying out examples to learn the basic concepts.
<template>
  /*<p v-bind:class="['bold', 'italic', isValid ? 'valid' : 'invalid']">*/

  <p v-bind:class="classArray">
    Hello, {{name[0]}} {{name[1]}}
  </p>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data() {
    return {     
      isValid: true,
      name: ['John','Doe'],
      classArray: ['bold', 'italic', isValid ? 'valid' : 'invalid']
      
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
  .bold    { font-weight: bolder }
  .italic  { font-style:  italic }
  .valid   { color: forestgreen  }
  .invalid { color: crimson      }
</style>

Above code throws up the following error -

ERROR
[eslint]
/js/vue3/src/App.vue
16:38  error  'isValid' is not defined  no-undef

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
How do I access 'isValid' inside the classArray?

You cannot reference a property of an object inside the object initializer. You have to do that after the object is complete.

And even if you fix that, it will always be true because you just initialized it. I assume you want classArray to change when you reassign isValid. You'll need to define a setter for isValid that updates classArray.

You can maube use a computed property for classArray so that it can correctly reference isValid from the component's data. Have a shot
<template>
  <p v-bind:class="classArray">
    Hello, {{ name[0] }} {{ name[1] }}
  </p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {     
      isValid: true,
      name: ['John', 'Doe']
    }
  },
  computed: {
    classArray() {
      return ['bold', 'italic', this.isValid ? 'valid' : 'invalid'];
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
  .bold    { font-weight: bolder }
  .italic  { font-style:  italic }
  .valid   { color: forestgreen  }
  .invalid { color: crimson      }
</style>


Thank you. It worked. Learned new ways to achieve the desired result.

@VenkatD This is how this is commonly done, not like suggested in the accepted answer

Define classArray as a getter that checks the current value of isValid of the object.
export default {
  data() {
    return {     
      isValid: true,
      name: ['John','Doe'],
      get classArray() { return ['bold', 'italic', this.isValid ? 'valid' : 'invalid']; }
      
    }
  }
}


A getter in data() is a bad suggestion. You won't find this mentioned in the docs, and I cannot predict the possible consequences. Another answer is correct, this is what computeds are for.

@EstusFlask This is a more general solution, not specific to vue.js, which I'm not familiar with.
